# How to convert Collection to Iterables?

Tags: java, guava

I have method, which returns `java.util.Collection`

I want to use `Iterables.find`

How can I make it?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. `Collections2<E>` just has static methods. You can't create an instance of it. `Iterables<E>` is the same. You can't convert between them because you never have an instance of either of them... It would really help if you could post a short but complete example of what you mean.

Comment: *You can't create an instance of it*. please show

Comment: Um, how can I show something that's impossible? Why don't you try to create an instance of `Collections2<Integer>` or `Iterables<Integer>`? The sample you've now provided seems irrelevant to the question, as it doesn't refer to `Collections2`.

Comment: If that's what you want to achieve, why not use `contains` method in `List`?

Comment: I don't know how can I get Iterables if I have List

Comment: tonga, it is simple examlpe only

Comment: It doesn't make sense to "convert" a `List` to an `Iterable` if you only want to find an element in it! So, explain what you really want to do!

Comment: parameter input for Iterables.find - Iterables

Comment: `Iterables` is also a class of static methods. If you want an `Iterable`, then anything that implements `List` also implements `Iterable` by definition. `Iterables.find()` takes a parameter of type  `Iterable` so your `List` is fine. Is this possibly what you're trying to find out?!

Comment: A `List` is already an `Iterable`, you do not need to convert it. You can just pass it to the `Iterables.find` method.

Comment: sorry, stupid question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have `Collections2<Integer>`

I'd bet you do not. You can't instantiate `Collections2` (apart from reflection) and even if you did, it's not parametrized.

> Hence I want to convert it to `Iterables<Integer>`

Assuming you mean `Iterable<Integer>`, this line should do:

```
Iterable<Integer> = yourIntegerList;
```

If you want to use `Iterables` with a `List`, just do it:

```
Iterables.contains(yourIntegerList, 2)
```

But there's the old simple way for `List`s: Do just `yourIntegerList.contains(2)`.

#### Update for the updated question

Nothing changes, each `Collection` is an `Iterable`, too.

**Just do it. In case you get an error, show it to us.** Otherwise, the only thing we know, is that you're currently rather confused w.r.t. the hierarchy.

Comment: @gstackoverflow: No problem. If you find it stupid now, it means you've learned something well.

Answer (score 0):

> I have method, which returns `Collection`

Looking at the JavaDoc for [`Collection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) you will see it has a SuperInterface of [`Iterable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html). Since this is what you need for the first parameter of [`Iterables.find()`](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html) you have what you need. Create a `Function` to find with and you've got everything you need.